# Boundaries of (probability distribution) function parameters in R?

Tags: r, search, probability-distribution

I would like to know without checking the documentation, what values a probability distribution accepts as arguments.

A single parameter can be a:

1. double between -Inf and Inf
2. double between 0 and Inf
3. positive integer
4. double between 0 and 1

(I know, for example, multinomial distribution has vector arguments, but let's concentrate now on the distribution having scalar arguments.)

```
library(dplyr)

checkArgBoundaries <- function(distribution) {

    #The number of parameters the distribution has
    nparams <- formals(get(paste0("r",distribution))) %>% names %>% {.[!(. %in% c("n","ncp"))]} %>% length
    
    while(TRUE) {
        canWeBreak <- tryCatch({
            #This is problematic, since we should generate value candidates representing the boundaries here. 
            do.call(get(paste0("r",distribution)), valuecandidates)
            TRUE
        }, warning = \(w) {
            FALSE
        }

        if(canWeBreak) {break}
    }

}
```

And for binomial distribution, for example, we should get a result that the size argument should be a positive integer and the prob argument should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: R does not make this information known from the function signature. You have to check the documentation to know what range of values make sense for each of the parameters. R is not a strongly typed language. Also R doesn't really have scalars, everything is a vector. A "scalar" is just a vector of length 1 in R.

Comment: Even if MrFlick's totally correct comment did not hold, there's also some issues in R semantics in the code. `do.call` takes a function name as a character value, so there's no need for the `get`. Using "r" as the prefix will get a random number generator rather than a probability function.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking focus. You might imagine that some of the packages that provide high level representations of probability functions might have some potential of being searched for error messages that could be extracted from the function bodies, but I think it is out of bounds to expect us to attempt inventing as testing  such an task.